# Database Searching Using Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

So I'm currently trying to perform a simple search using Symfony2 and Doctrine. Something similar to this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/searching.html

I've currently got the following `YAML` file setup to generate my entities. It generates my `class Style` entity correctly as a class.

```
...\Style:
    type: entity
    table: styles
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    actAs:
        Searchable:
            fields: [title]
            batchUpdates: true
    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: 150
            unique: true
```

In my controller, I'm trying to run a search on that table based on a string.

```
public function searchAction($pattern) 
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('..:Style');
    $search = $repository->search($pattern);

    return $this->outputize($search);
}
```

However, when I try executing the code, I get the following exception.

```
Undefined method 'search'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

Am I generating my entities correctly or is there something I'm clearly missing?

On a side note, when I look at my `Entity/Style.php` after generating, there is no clear method `->search()`, is the function supposed to be generated by Symfony here?

Comment: Be aware that the default doctrine version used in symfony 2 is 2.x, and that what you get by doing `$this->getDoctrine()` is probably a doctrine 2 class and not a doctrine 1 class ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`search()` is not a function supported in Symfony2. You're looking at the Symfony 1.x documentation, and Symfony2 is really different from Symfony 1.x so for reference, you should always use [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html).

There are several ways to fetch entities in Symfony2. Here are a few examples:

1. Find

   ```
   $user = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
       ->find($user_id)
   ;
   ```
2. DQL:

   ```
   $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT b FROM YourBundle:Bid b WHERE b.property_id = :property_id ORDER BY b.amount DESC'
   )->setParameter('property_id', $property_id);
   try {
       $bids = $query->getResult();
   } catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
       //Handle No Result Exception here
   }
   ```

Refer to the Doctrine guide for Symfony2 here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: I was trying to perform a search, similar to `mysql fulltext` search ability.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use WHERE clause to search through LONGTEXT/BLOB field, but I cannot add index for it.
Also I don't have a possibility to add some Apache addon like Lucene.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can do it in symfony 3

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT p
                FROM AppBundle:Hotel p
                WHERE p.address like :location
                ORDER BY p.address ASC'
                )->setParameter('location','%'.$request->get('location').'%' );
$hotel = $query->getResult();
```